# TCP Approach on the iOS platform

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, sockets, tcp

I am currently working on an app which needs to communicate with a server. I am going to transfer packets of two different sizes, a small packet for small data (such as sql requests), and a big packet for files (or pieces of files, when the files exceed 1024bytes). These packets look like this:

Small packet:

```
typedef struct small_packet {
    int msgtype:8;
    int size:16;
    int following:24;
    char data1[64];
    char data2[64];
} packet;
```

Large packet:

```
typedef struct file_packet {
    int msgtype:8; //For partial file packet this should be 0x02
    int size:16;
    int following:24;
    char data1[64];
    char fileBuffer[1024];
} filePacket;
```

I have written the basic parts of the server in C++ using select(). The server now accepts incoming connections, and returns a list of games when a client requests it. I have tested this with a simple client written in C.

My protocol requirements for server communication look like this:

```
 *
 * Message types:
 * 0x01: Login message. Data1 is username, data2 is pw hash
 * 0x02: Login accepted/failed. Data1 is 1 for accept or 0 for not accepted
 * 0x03: New user. Data1 is username, data2 is pw hash
 * 0x04: New user accepted/failed. Data1 is 1 for accept and 0 for error
 * 0x05: Friend list request. Data1 is username and data2 should be 0
 * 0x06: Friend list header. Data1 is username and data2 should be 0
 * 0x07: Friend list packet. Data1 is username, data2 is 0
 * 0x08: Game list request. Data1 is username, data2 is 0
 * 0x09: Game list header. Data1 is username, data2 is game id
 * 0x0A: Game list packet. Following is gameID, data1 is randomness (0 or 1, first bit), data2 is players (divided by semicolon)
 * 0x0B: Friend add. Data1 is username, data2 is friend username
 * 0x0C: Random game add. Data1 is username, data2 is 0
 * 0x0D: Friend game add. Data1 is username, filebuffer holds friends' usernames, divided by semicolons
 * 0x10: File add. Data1 is username, data2 is game id
 * 0x11: File request. Data1 is username, data2 is game id
 * 0x12: File header. Data1 is turn number, data2 is game id
 * 0x13: File part. Data1 is 0, filebuffer is filepart
 *
```

Now here comes the tricky part; what approach to socket programming for the iOS platform should I take? Right now I have a CFRead/WriteStreamRef & NSInput/OutputStream socket communicator class which has a stream function that switches over eventCodes (such as NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable). This doesn't seem to work too well. Either I am doing something wrong, or I have trouble with either requests being answered too slowly, or blocking reads. Either way, right now I only get the 0x09 reply when requesting a game list. The rest is either never received by the client, or dropped because the program has moved past the reading (I don't know how).

I am thinking of switching to the wonderful [CocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket) API, but rewriting my code isn't very tempting.

Is there a way to write a simple TCP client for the iPhone which does not block, and receives data which may be cast to a C-style struct? Do I have to redefine my structs, or even use something else for the data? I'd love examples, or good links (and trust me, I've gooooooooogled!).

Any help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might read [this short intro](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket/wiki/Intro_GCDAsyncSocket) on using CocoaAsyncSocket.

You can easily establish a connection by:

```
GCDAsyncSocket *socket = [[GCDAsyncSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
```

connect to your server:

```
NSError *err = nil;
if (![socket connectToHost:@"yourserverip" onPort:80 error:&err]) // Asynchronous!
{
// If there was an error, it's likely something like "already connected" or "no delegate set"
NSLog(@"I goofed: %@", err);
}
```

Now put your struct(s) to NSData:

```
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithBytes:&myFilePacket length:sizeof(myFilePacket)];
```

and finally send your data:

```
[socket writeData:myData withTimeout:-1 tag:1];
```

CocoaAsyncSocket also offers a lot of useful callback methods like:

```
- (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didWriteDataWithTag:(long)tag
```

or for incoming packets you can cast NSData back to struct:

```
- (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sender didReadData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag
{
  filePacket packet;
  [data getBytes:&packet length:sizeof(packet)];
}
```

and so on...
Have a look at the header files...

Yes, it is as simple as that.

Comment: Thank you, I have rewritten parts of my servercomm using AsyncSocket now. The server seems to accept the client, and it returns packets on request, but my client does not read the packets sent by the server. To me it seems like the - (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sender didReadData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag delegate function is never called back. Strange... O well back to debugging.

Again thanks :)

Comment: You might declare `GCDAsyncSocket *socket` as property or instance variable. Otherwise it might be destroyed after your data was sent.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working @chris. I still don't know why it doesn't fire that certain delegate function when the delegate function for didWrite and didConnect work.

Comment: You could put an NSLog message into `- (void)socketDidDisconnect:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock withError:(NSError *)err;` callback method in order to see if your socket disconnected for any reason.